# Labeling linguistic examples with language information

Tags: linguistics, gb4e, cgloss4e

I'm writing a linguistics paper that uses a large amount of linguistic examples from a wide variety of languages, using the gb4e package. I want to be able to label each example with information about the language it comes from, as I've seen in some texts, sort of like this:

> ```
> Language (family, citation, etc.)  
>    (1) example text  
>        glosses
>        'translation'
> ```

gb4e is great at formatting the examples themselves, but I can't seem to get the label placed where I want it, that is, placed immediately before the example and without an indent. Here's some example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

Hungarian (Finn-Ugric, \emph{reference})  
\begin{exe}  
\ex \gll    J\'anos h\'aza\\  
            John house.his\\  
    \glt    `John's house'  
\end{exe}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

If the label text is outside the exe environment, it's treated like a regular paragraph, but if I try to put it inside, it gives me an error. How can I make it look the way I want? I've looked at other packages that do numbered examples, but they don't seem to have solutions either, and they also don't have the same functionality as gb4e that I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have edited your question to include `lipsum` package for introducing dummy text for better readability and focus, you can also use egreg's `kantlipsum` package for the same purpose. Please rollback if this is not desired.

Comment: Didn't even know those existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use Alexis Dimitriadis' version of `cgloss4e` available here as [`cgloss.sty`](https://staticweb.hum.uu.nl/medewerkers/alexis.dimitriadis/latex/cgloss.sty) you can put language information right aligned with the first line of the example.  This is IMO a very nice way to format such information, and quite common in the field.

It is *not* possible with this solution to put right aligned materials on the same line as the gloss itself, but it is possible (if needed) to put material on the `\glt` line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

 
\begin{exe}  
\ex \gll    J\'anos h\'aza\\ 
            John house.his\\ \hfill Hungarian (Finno-Ugric, \emph{reference}) 
    \glt    `John's house'  
\end{exe}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

#### Solution also works with `linguex`

Another popular package for formatting linguistic examples is the `linguex` package. Since `linguex` also uses `cgloss4e`, the solution given above will also work. Here's the same example using the `linguex` commands. The order of loading the packages matters: `cgloss` must be loaded after `linguex` is loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\exg. 
   J\'anos h\'aza\\ 
   John house.his\\ \hfill Hungarian (Finno-Ugric, \emph{reference}) 
   \glt    `John's house'  

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: That does look nice. Does cgloss4e otherwise work the same as gb4e? I noticed it's not included in Texlive.

Comment: `cgloss4e` is loaded by `gb4e`; it's the part that handles the glosses and part of the regular `gb4e` distribution. You don't see it because you usually never load it by itself.  `cgloss` is a replacement for `cgloss4e` not for `gb4e` itself.  But yes, it works identically as far as I know.  I'm not sure why Alexis has never put it up on CTAN.

Comment: So if I load `cgloss`, does it automatically replace `cgloss4e`? Also, should it be loaded before or after `gb4e`? I've discovered that `gb4e` usually needs to be loaded last or it causes problems.

Comment: Yes.  You should load it after `gb4e`.  And yes, `gb4e` should be loaded almost last since it messes with the category codes of `_` and `^`.

Comment: [Here's a question related to this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592641/using-hfill-with-cgloss4e).

Comment: But how do you actually install *cgloss.sty* since it's not listed in `MikTeX`? I created the folder `cgloss`, put the file in it. I updated the package database in `MikTeX`....

Comment: You install it in your local `texmf` tree as with any other local addition. I don’t use MikTeX but there are plenty of questions about adding local packages here on the site if you need more detail.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is an old question, but for posterity's sake, I thought I'd point out that [`expex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex) provides several ways to include language name or other example annotations.

### Right-aligned, on first gloss line

This is the format suggested in the answer by @Alan Munn:

[image]

**Explanation**

Use `\rightcomment{}` between `\gla` and the first word. See section 11.2 of the [`expex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/expex/expex-doc.pdf).

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=, belowglpreambleskip=-0.5ex, aboveglftskip=-0.5ex} % gloss formatting

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2]  

    \ex
    \begingl
    \gla\rightcomment{Hungarian (Finno-Ugric, \emph{reference})}J\'anos h\'aza//
    \glb John house.his//
    \glft `John's house'//
    \endgl
    \xe

    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

### Within example, above gloss lines

This is the format suggested in the answer by @cbowern:

[image]

**Explanation**

Use `\glpreamble` to introduce the preamble line above the first gloss line. Formatting of the gloss preamble line can be controlled globally or locally by the parameter `everyglpreamble`. The vertical space between the gloss preamble and the first gloss line can be controlled by the parameter `belowglpreambleskip`. See section 9 of the [`expex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/expex/expex-doc.pdf).

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=, belowglpreambleskip=-0.5ex, aboveglftskip=-0.5ex} % gloss formatting

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2]  

    \ex
    \begingl
    \glpreamble Hungarian (Finno-Ugric, \emph{reference})//
    \gla J\'anos h\'aza //
    \glb John house.his//
    \glft `John's house' //
    \endgl
    \xe

    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

### Left-aligned, above the example

This is the format suggested in the original question:

[image]

**Explanation**

`expex` doesn't provide a special command for this format, but it's still pretty simple to produce. The code below creates a command `\langlabel` that removes the paragraph indent and adds the vertical space that normally appears above examples. It then uses `\ex~` instead of `\ex` so that there is no vertical space between the label and the example.

By default, example numbers produced by `expex` are flush with the left margin (unlike in `gb4e`, where they are indented). If you want to indent the example numbers in `expex`, use the parameter `numoffset`. See sections 4 and 5 of the [`expex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/expex/expex-doc.pdf).

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\newlength{\aboveexskip} % creates a length \aboveexskip
\setlength{\aboveexskip}{2.7ex plus .4ex minus .4ex} % sets a value for \aboveexskip (this the default value for vertical space above examples taken from the expex documentation)
\lingset{aboveexskip=\aboveexskip, everygla=, belowglpreambleskip=-0.5ex, aboveglftskip=-0.5ex} % gloss formatting, aboveexskip=\aboveexskip sets the expex parameter aboveexskip to the length specified in the line above

\newcommand{\langlabel}[1]{\vspace{\aboveexskip}\noindent{#1}} % \aboveexskip is used here because \ex~ will remove the vertical spacing above the example

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2]  

    \langlabel{Hungarian (Finno-Ugric, \emph{reference})}
    \ex~ % use the ~ version with \langlabel unless you want vertical space between the label and the example
    \begingl
    \gla J\'anos h\'aza //
    \glb John house.his//
    \glft `John's house' //
    \endgl
    \xe

    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (rather ugly) solution by wrapping the language label in an un-numbered example via `\sn`:

```
\newcommand\langlabel[1]{\sn\hspace*{-\leftmargin}{#1}\\[-1em]}
...
\begin{exe}  
\langlabel{Hungarian (Finn-Ugric, \emph{reference})}
\ex \gll    J\'anos h\'aza\\  
            John house.his\\  
    \glt    `John's house'  
\end{exe}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also just put the language label between the \ex and \gll commands:

```
\begin{exe}  
\ex Hungarian (Finn-Ugric, \emph{reference}) \gll    J\'anos h\'aza\\  
            John house.his\\  
    \glt    `John's house'  
\end{exe}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `linguex`, you might encounter an error if you use Alan's method from answer #1 above. I had to replace l.361--63 of `linguex.sty`,...

```
\def\gl@stop{{\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline\end{flushleft}%
         \global\glossfalse%
         \ifindex\expandafter\lookforwords\fi {} }
```

...with the following:

```
\def\gl@stop{{\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline\leavevmode \egroup 
         \global\glossfalse%
         \ifindex\expandafter\lookforwords\fi {} }
```

The reason was that `cgloss` redefines `\gl@stop`, but then `linguex` re-re-defines it. The changes above avoid that problem by combining both re-definitions.

In addition, replace line 34 in `linguex.sty`...

```
\RequirePackage{xspace,cgloss4e}
```

...by...

```
\RequirePackage{xspace,cgloss}
```

...and `linguex` loads `cgloss`, so you don't have to call it seperately.

It works fine on my installation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You can add highlighting of code by selecting it and hitting Ctrl + K (or click the button marked `{}` above the answer field. Blocks are indented by four spaces, inline code placed between backticks (`\``).

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this doesn't answer the OP's specific question, it relates to the same issue as in the question title.

If you use `linguex` then I think the best solution is to simply place the `\hfill Language info` after the translation line, which of course aligns your language info to the last line of your glossed example, but this avoids far worse problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\exg. Gianni teme questo.\\
      Gianni fears this\\ 
      `Gianni fears this' \hfill Experiencer subjects

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: last line language info with linguex]

The problem with all of the above solutions for people who already use `linguex` is that

1. you have to modify `linguex.sty` as per Daniel Büring's response above and/or download and install `cgloss` as all the previous answers suggest, and more importantly
2. you'll have to modify the way you write ALL your `linguex` glossed examples to include `\glt` at the beginning of the translation line. I use `\exg.` all the time and don't always need extra info right aligned alongside it so I don't want to re-write all of my examples according to what the `cgloss` package requires.

Comment: Note that this also works for `gb4e` without `cgloss`, with the same advantages and disadvantages as noted in this answer.