# How do I right-align text in a glossed Linguex example?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguex

I use the Linguex package for examples with glosses (word-for-word translations) and I want to add right-aligned comments to specify the language of my examples, but this doesn't work with glossed examples. I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}

\exg. J'ai deux pommes.\hfill{French}\\
      {I have} two apples.\
\end{document}
```

The \ \ is necessary when you add glosses and can't be omitted. I also tried using flushright and raggedright, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following question: [Labeling linguistic examples with language information](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49579) `linguex` also uses `cgloss4e` to format glosses, so the solution posted there (use the `cgloss` package instead) works too.

Comment: @Thomas Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the comment ends up below the example if I try that, even if I copy and paste the code exactly. http://i.imgur.com/ePeB4Tw.png

Comment: @Thomas Did you put the `cgloss` package in your local `texmf` folder, add `\usepackage{cgloss}` (after loading `linguex)` and replace the `gb4e` code with the equivalent `linguex` code? I've added the `linguex` code to the linked answer. If you're still having problems, edit your question to include the revised code and we can reopen the question.

Comment: I got it to work, thank you very much for all your help!