# Beamer, philex and \hfill

Tags: beamer, spacing, linguistics

I'm using the package `philex` for linguistic examples, and I try to put a textual element at the end of the line (right centered). I tried to use the `\hfill`command, but as the MWE will show you, it does not provide a coherent alignment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{philex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{The syntactic ambiguity}
    \lb{}{
        \lba{}{Fred eats an apple. \hfill (a)}
        \lbz{}{Fred eats an apple. \hfill (a)}  
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Can someone help me fix this odd behavior?

Comment: `\lba{}{Fred eats an apple. \hfill\rlap{\hspace{3ex}(a)}}` will get you going until someone can offer a less kludgey answer.

Comment: This is not a `beamer` issue. I get the same spacing if I use `article` and delete the `frame` environment.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid `philex` for the reasons egreg gives in his answer. The most commonly used packages for typesetting linguistic examples are [`gb4e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e), [`expex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/expex), and [`linguex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/linguex) (which is loaded by `philex`). See [Alan Munn's excellent comparison of these packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77941/42880) for more details. 
Many of the features that `philex` adds to `linguex` (cross-referencing, repeating examples, label customization, etc.) are available in `expex`.

All of these packages allow you to have a right-aligned comment. See the answers to [Labeling linguistic examples with language information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49579/labeling-linguistic-examples-with-language-information) for code that illustrates how to do this in each package. `expex` is the only one that provide a native command for these right-aligned comments: `\rightcomment`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the `philex` package is written in a terrible way and doesn't protect end-of-lines in definitions. The space you see is caused mainly by these unprotected spaces.

See [When is it harmful to add percent character at end of lines in a \newcommand, or similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34844/when-is-it-harmful-to-add-percent-character-at-end-of-lines-in-a-newcommand-or) for more information.

They are too many unprotected end-of-lines for proposing a fix; there's also the problem that the macro definitions are very big and don't use modularity.

You can “fix” the issue by using a wild hack; this may however give unexpected results if a space was really needed at some point of a definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\endlinechar=-1
\usepackage{philex}
\endlinechar=13

\begin{document}

\lb{y}{%
   \lba{y1}{Fred eats an apple. \hfill (a)}%
   \lbz{y2}{Fred eats an apple. \hfill (a)}%
}

\end{document}
```

Note that end of lines must be protected also in the input. The `showframe` package is just for demonstrate the alignment to the margin.

[image]

The real fix is not using the package and ask its maintainer to correct the bad code.

Just to show an example, here is the definition of `\lb` (line numbers added for convenience)

```
 95 \newcommand{\lb}[3][n]{
 96 \ifdim\lastskip=\Extopsep\vspace\Exredux\else \fi
 97 \immediate\write\@auxout{\unexpanded{\expandafter\gdef\csname#2r\endcsname{#3}\expandafter\gdef\csname#2\endcsname{\ref{#2}}
 98 \expandafter\gdef\csname#2p\endcsname{\MakeLowercase#3}}}
 99 \expandafter\providecommand\expandafter{\csname#2r\endcsname}{#3}
100 \expandafter\providecommand\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\ref{#2}}\expandafter\providecommand\expandafter{\csname#2p\endcsname}{\MakeLowercase#3}
101 \ifhyperref%
102 \renewcommand{\theFnExNo}{\roman{FnExNo}}
103 \ex. \label{#2} \if#1c \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1ex}
104 \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2ex}%
105 \parbox{\centro}{\centering \hypertarget{#2}{#3}\philpunct}\else \hypertarget{#2}{#3}\philpunct\fi\par
106 \else 
107 \ex. \label{#2} \if#1c \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1ex}\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2ex}%
108 \parbox{\centro}{\centering #3\philpunct}\else #3\philpunct\fi\par%
109 \fi}
```

There are missing `%` at the end of lines 95, 97, 98, 99, 100, 102, and 103. The `%` at the end of lines 101 and 108 are redundant (the line ends with a control word). The only correctly placed `%` characters are at the end of lines 104 and 107.

The definition of `\lba` is similarly flawed.