# Using hfill with cgloss4e

Tags: enumerate, linguistics, linguex, cgloss4e, gloss

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49583/181940) shows how to use \hfill in glosses within linguex. I can't seem to load "cgloss.sty" that is mentioned in the answer to Overleaf (by adding `usepackage{cgloss}` in the preamble -- or am I supposed to do something different?), and I suppose it's been superseded by "cgloss4e.sty" (at least [linguex documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/linguex/doc/linguex-doc.pdf) only mentions "cgloss4e"). If I use "cgloss4e.sty", then I end up with this:

[image]

instead of

[image]

(I used the example from the answer referred to above).
How to make this look properly?

Comment: Not much help, but the `clgioss.sty` mentioned in the original article was *not* on CTAN and only available from the author's website, **but** the link to the author's website is now defunct. The mentioned `cgloss.sty` was a modified version of `cgloss4e.sty` which is why you're seeing different results.

Comment: I've fixed the link in the original question. There you can get a copy of `cgloss.sty`. Thanks for pointing out the dead link @DonHosek.