# Node names are too long for forest

Tags: nodes, forest, trees

I've been trying to draw a tree like this:

[image]

But I came across the problem that the node names are apparently too long... So the code below doesn't work. (If you replace `$\lambda x.\lambda e. \text{eating}(e) \land \text{agent}(e,x) \land \text{theme}(e, \textsc{food}) \land \textsc{benefactive}(e,\text{wife})$` with `aaa`, it will work.) Is there any way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
%\usepackage{cgloss}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}

\ex.
\begin{forest}
[\textbf{VoiceP}
    [he]
    [$\lambda x.\lambda e. \text{eating}(e) \land \text{agent}(e,x) \land \text{theme}(e, \textsc{food}) \land \textsc{benefactive}(e,\text{wife})$
       [T\\will ]
       [VP
          [V\\eat ]
          [DP [D\\a ] [NP [N\\burger ]]]
       ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

(Source of the code above before my modifications: https://amunn.github.io/assets/latex/overleaf-trees.pdf)

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is `cgloss`?

Comment: @SandyG it's discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49579/labeling-linguistic-examples-with-language-information/49583#49583). But I guess for the purpose of this question, it's not important, you can delete the line with cgloss.

Comment: It still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside forest nodes commas differs node content from eventual local style settings. So in the cases, when node content should contain commas, whole node content had to be encapsulated in curly braces:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree = {
    align=center,
            }
[\textbf{VoiceP}
    [he]
    [${\lambda x.\lambda e. \text{eating}(e) \land \text{agent}(e,x)}$\\
     ${\land\, \text{theme}(e,\textsc{food}) \textsc{benefactive}(e,\text{wife})}$, draw
       [T\\will ]
       [VP
          [V\\eat ]
          [DP   [D\\a ] 
                [NP 
                    [N\\burger ]
                ]
          ]
       ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]