# Adding a line of text in glossed examples

Tags: linguistics, linguex

Here's the code I'm working with (you need [cgloss.sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49583/181940) to run it):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\begin{document}

\ex.
\ag. This is a sentence. \\
a b c d\\ \hfil{lalalala}
\glt `blah'
\bg. This is a sentence. \\
a b c d\\ \hfil{lalalala}
\glt `blah'

\end{document}
```

It produces the following:

[image]

Is there a way to modify it to make it look something like this:

[image]

That is, I want to have a line with "Context" just above the lines that contain "This is a sentence" in my example. If I just use `\\`, this messes up the inter-linear glossing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another reason not to use `linguex`. :) If you're not committed to it, I would recommend `gb4e` instead.  But if you are committed to it, you can do what you want by using the `cgloss4e` glossing macros directly rather than the `linguex` wrappers.

### Using `linguex` alone

Because `linguex` adds a small vertical space in the `\ex.` line, I've made a corresponding `\ix.` command to use when an example has the introduction line. If you like the small extra space (as in the second version of my sample code) then you don't need the `\ix.` command at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex}
\def\ix.{\ex.\setlength{\Extopsep}{0pt}}
\begin{document}
\ix. 
\a. This is an introductory sentence describing the context.
\gll This is a gloss\\
This is another gloss\\
\glt `This is a translation.'

\ex. 
\a. This is an introductory sentence describing the context.
\gll This is a gloss\\
This is another gloss\\
\glt `This is a translation.'

\end{document}
```

[image: output of linguex code]

### Using `linguex` with `cgloss`

If you are also using `cgloss`, then the solution actually turns out to be simpler, we just need to add a zero length `\vskip` to the `\gll` command, which we can do using the `etoolbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex,cgloss}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\gll}{\vskip0pt}{}{}
\begin{document}
\ex. 
\a. This is an introductory sentence describing the context.
\gll This is a gloss\\
This is another gloss\\
\glt `This is a translation.'\hfill (Language information)

\end{document}
```

[image: output of cgloss code]

Comment: Thanks! What if some of my prior examples use cgloss.sty (in order to make hfill work properly)? This doesn't seem to work together with cgloss. Is there a way to either make it work with cgloss, or make hfill (or something similar) work without cgloss?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t have `cgloss` installed on the machine I wrote the answer on and assumed it wouldn’t make a difference.  I’ll take a look.

Comment: The `cgloss` solution turns out to be simpler, and I've updated the answer but I've kept the `linguex` solution in the answer as well for those who might not be using `cgloss`.

Comment: Thank you!! If the "introductory sentence" takes several lines, do you think any further modifications (in terms of spacing between those lines) are needed to make readability even better? (I'm thinking maybe if the spacing between the gloss and translation is the same as the spacing between the lines in the "introductory sentence", that could improve readability?)

Comment: It might do. That's an aesthetic choice you have to make. But you can adjust the `\vskip` amount to something greater than `0pt`. `cgloss` defines a `\gltoffset` macro (default is `0pt`) which will put space between the gloss and the translation. If you you use `\gltoffset` as the value you use for the `\vskip` in the adjusted `\gll` command you can have equal space above and below. N.B. `\gltoffset` is a macro not a length, so you set it with `\renewcommand{\gltoffset}{...}` not `\setlength`.